# MySQL Error: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

[image]

I am able to successfully insert a row in the **business** table but not the **business_contact** table. Whenever I try to insert a row in the **business_contact** table I get the following error:

***#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails***

Although the row that I'm attempting to insert into the **business_contact** table has a *BusinessID* that already exists in the **business** table.

**business_contact** failed insert statement

```
INSERT INTO business_contact(BusinessID, BusinessContactTypeID, BusinessContactData) VALUES (1, 1, '0097336031000');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the following in your `business` and `contact_type_lookup` table:
 1. `business` table has `BusinessID` value that you are trying to insert into `business_contact
 2.`contact_type_lookup`table has`ContactTypeID`value that you are trying to insert into business_contact`

This error is related to either missing `BusinessID` and or missing `ContactTypeID`.  To verify this please select the `BusinessID` record from `business` table and `ContactTypeID` from `contact_type_lookup` table.

For example: 
If you are executing the following query:

```
insert into business_contact(BusinessContactID, BusinessID, BusinessContactTypeID, BusinessContactData) values ('1', '2', '3', 'This is the business contact data');
```

Then, ensure that the following queries returns valid results:

```
select BusinessID from business where BusinessID = 2;

select ContactTypeID from business_contact_type where ContactTypeID = 3;
```

Comment: I verified that both rows exists yet I'm getting the same error. If it helps, this is the exact error message: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`algallaf_dev`.`business_contact`, CONSTRAINT `fk_BusinessContact_Business` FOREIGN KEY (`BusinessID`) REFERENCES `business` (`BusinessID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: Please post the results of the following: `desc business;` and `desc business_contact;`.  Also please share if you have any index.

Comment: I removed extra columns from the screenshot above hence you might find additional information. [desc business;](http://i.imgur.com/dVitFLb.png) & [desc business_contact;](http://i.imgur.com/0QNTbQW.png)

Comment: Successful ***business*** table insert
`INSERT INTO business(BusinessID, BusinessName, BusinessDescription) VALUE (1,"Stackoverflow"," Most Awesome Site in the World!");`

Successful ***contact_type_lookup*** table insert
`INSERT INTO contact_type_lookup(ContactTypeID, ContactTypeDescription)  VALUE (1, "Website");`

Failed ***business_contact*** table insert
`INSERT INTO business_contact(BusinessID, BusinessContactTypeID, BusinessContactData) VALUE (1,1,"+973-36031000");`

Comment: What happens when you do the following: `insert into business_contact(BusinessContactID, BusinessID, BusinessContactTypeID, BusinessContactData) values (1, 1, 1, '+973-36031000')`.  

Also you have a syntax error in your last query: It should be `values` not `value`. (plural).

Comment: Just wanted to share my attempt to INSERT using PHPMyAdmin. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/9p9a99N.png) I get the same error too.

Comment: I tested the insert locally on my Windows workstation using WAMP and it successfully inserted but my remote online server is Linux didn't. Might that be a reason?

Comment: That shouldn't be a reason unless the schema is different.  You should find out the difference between the two schemas.

Comment: I changed the ***business*** table engine from _MyISAM_ to _InnoDB_ and the solved the issue. Thanks for your help.